# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass - help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am teaching myself Ruby on Rails and trying to build a blog through a tutorial. I saw some of these answers, and it seems as though my syntax is right, but I'm getting the error in the title.

Here is my articles_controller code:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_article, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

    def index
        @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        @article.user = User.first
        if @article.save
            flash[:success] = "Article was successfully created"
            redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        if @article.update(article_params)
            flash[:success] = "Article was updated"
            redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Article was not updated"
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def show

    end

    def destroy
        @article.destroy
        flash[:danger] = "Article was deleted"
        redirect_to articles_path
    end

    private
        def set_article
            @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        end

        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
        end
end
```

And here is my index.html.erb:

```rb
<h1 align="center">Listing all articles</h1>
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
   <div class="well well-lg">
    <div class="article-title">
     <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
    </div>
    <div class="article-body">
     <%= truncate(article.description, length: 100) %>
</div>
    <div class="article-meta-details">
     <small>Created by: <%= article.user.username if article.user %>, <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %> ago, last updated: <%= time_ago_in_words(article.updated_at) %> ago</small>
    </div>
    <div class="article-actions">
     <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(article), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this article?"}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: 1. when do you get the error? visiting what route?
2. the stacktrace would be quite helpful
3. please post the other tempates as well, if the issue may be there

Comment: Please add stack trace of the error and rails version that you're using

Comment: Based on the information you've given, it sounds like `@articles` is being set to `nil` in your `index` method. Does your `articles` table exist in your database?

Comment: @wvengen when I use "rails s" to start the server and log on to localhost:3000, this error happens.

Comment: @Vasfed I am using Rails 5.2.4.1.

Comment: @mharper I have an articles table.

Comment: Do you have other controllers that use the same view? Something like RootController or so? Please show your routes

Comment: Do you use will_paginate gem? Can you post the error info in the console? And can you post your routes? Do you have a route like `root  'articles#index'`?

Comment: @Feifei Xiong ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <h1 align="center">Listing all articles</h1>
    2: <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    3:  <div class="row">
    4:   <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    5:    <div class="well well-lg">

Comment: I tried root 'articles#index', and it didn't work. I have will_paginate. My roots are: Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#index'
  root 'articles#index'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users, except: [:new]

  resources :articles

end

Comment: @StuartKushner It looks like your code is fine. Could you try `Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)` in rails console? type `rails c` in the terminal and try it, to address the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your syntax in the `index` method is wrong.

```
@articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

Should be

```
@articles = Article.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```